# WMS Configuration

Tags: wms, deegree

I'm moving from deegree 3.3.2 to the newest version, but my configuration was dependent on UnrequestableLayer and RequestableLayer, which were deleted from wms_configuration.xds. Can I somehow make it work as it used to? Or how can I replace it so that it won't break the configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to migrate the deegree WMS configuration from an older version such as 3.3.2 to the most recent 3.4.16 version, check the following:

1. Is the `configVersion` in all configuration files set to the corresponding version of the deegree webapp? Apply the value "3.4.0" and update the referenced schema file in the `xsi:schemaLocation attribute`, e.g. http://schemas.deegree.org/services/wms/3.4.0/wms_configuration.xsd for the deegreeWMS config file. You may do the same for the other config files to.
2. Remove the unsupported tags and elements from the deegree WMS configuration.
3. If a themes configuration file does not exist, add this file to the deegree workspace. Check out the handbook for more information about Map Themes https://download.deegree.org/documentation/current/html/#anchor-configuration-themes.
4. In this configuration file you can apply the corresponding settings for requestable layers, see https://github.com/deegree/deegree3/blob/master/deegree-core/deegree-core-theme/src/main/resources/META-INF/schemas/themes/3.4.0/themes.xsd